# Wordpress creating custom fields in custom plugins code

Tags: wordpress, drupal, plugins, custom-fields

As per requirement, i need to create plugin with custom fields in the wordpress 3.0. I have a look at creating the plugins in wordpress. I can able to create the plugins with custom fields by hardcoded  HTML fields code. Like providing input type name id etc.

But I need to create the fields like textbox, image upload, buttons using wordpress custom fields functions. Just calling the functions with type the field need to generate the fields. As like I already did in the drupal 7.

Below is the sample code for creating the text field in the drupal 7

```
$form['posts']['Title'] = array(
    '#prefix' => '<div class="container-inline">',
    '#required' => '1',
    '#size' => '20',
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Title'),
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
);
```

Is it possible in the wordpress?. Please guide me in the wordpress to create the custom plugins. Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 1):

Here a sample of code I've used to add custom field in my custom post type.
or you can use the plugin [Advanced Custom Field](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) to add custom field and attached them to your custom post type.

I hope this can help you !

```
<?php
// Metabox declaration
$prefix = 'bookmark_';  

// The only way I found too pass the fields informations to the action
global $bookmark_meta_fields;
$bookmark_meta_fields = array(  
    array(  
        'label'=> 'Url',  
        'desc'  => 'Url of the bookmark.',  
        'id'    => $prefix.'url',  
        'type'  => 'text'  
    ),  
    array(  
        'label'=> 'Comments',  
        'desc'  => 'A small comments about the bookmarks.',  
        'id'    => $prefix.'comment',  
        'type'  => 'textarea'  
    ),  

); 



add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'vban_bookmark_metabox');

function vban_bookmark_metabox() {  
    add_meta_box(  
        'bookmark_info', // $id  
        'Bookmark info', // $title  
        'vban_bookmark_metabox_show', // $callback  
        'vbanBookmarks', // $page  
        'normal', // $context  
        'high'); // $priority  
}  

/*
* show metabox function
*/
function vban_bookmark_metabox_show() {  
    global $bookmark_meta_fields, $post;  
    // Use nonce for verification  
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="custom_meta_box_nonce" value="'.wp_create_nonce(basename(__FILE__)).'" />';  
    // Begin the field table and loop  
    echo '<table class="form-table">';  
    foreach ($bookmark_meta_fields as $field) {  
        // get value of this field if it exists for this post  
        $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field['id'], true);  
        // begin a table row with  
        echo '<tr> 
                <th><label for="'.$field['id'].'">'.$field['label'].'</label></th> 
                <td>';  
                switch($field['type']) {  
                   case 'text':  
                        echo '<input type="text" name="'.$field['id'].'" id="'.$field['id'].'" value="'.$meta.'" size="30" />
                        <br /><span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'</span>';
                        // textarea  
                    break; 
                    case 'textarea':  
                        echo '<textarea name="'.$field['id'].'" id="'.$field['id'].'" cols="60" rows="4">'.$meta.'</textarea> 
                            <br /><span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'</span>';  
                    break;    

                } //end switch  
        echo '</td></tr>';  
    } // end foreach  
    echo '</table>'; // end table  
} 




/*
* SAVE metabox custom_field
*/

add_action('save_post', 'vban_bookmark_metabox_save');

// Save the Data  
function vban_bookmark_metabox_save($post_id) {  

    global $bookmark_meta_fields;  
    // verify nonce  
    if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['custom_meta_box_nonce'], basename(__FILE__))) {        
        return $post_id;  
    } 

    // check autosave  
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE){
         return $post_id;
    }

    // check permissions  
    if ('vbanBookmarks' == $_POST['post_type']) {  
        if (!current_user_can('edit_bookmark', $post_id))
            return $post_id;  
        } elseif (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {
            return $post_id;  
        }
    // loop through fields and save the data  
    foreach ($bookmark_meta_fields as $field) {  

        $old = get_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], true);  
        $new = $_POST[$field['id']];  
        if ($new && $new != $old) {  
            update_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $new);  
        } elseif ('' == $new && $old) {  
            delete_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $old);  
        }  
    } // end foreach  
}  
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You might also take a look at this plug-in: Advanced Custom Post Types.

"This is a framework for creating not only custom post types, roles and taxonomies in WordPress but it will also give you the ability to rapidly create custom fields (post types only)."

https://github.com/kevindees/advanced_custom_post_types